# How do I change the /web directory?

Tags: craft3, control-panel, install

I'm extremely new to Craft CMS - I'm trying to install it on to a Cpanel as a test, upon downloading the CMS is gives you all the folders for craft, and then a separate /web folder.

If you move the contents of the /web folder outside of this, it causes an error. I've also tried moving the craft installation up one level, and then taking the contents of the /web folder out, but this also errors. am I missing something extremely obvious?

It's currently set up as a sub domain:

http://ea.cranberrywp.co.uk/web/

I'm looking to make it like this:

http://ea.cranberrywp.co.uk/

But as you can see that takes me to just the directory.

Sorry for the silly question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should point your domain to the /web folder and not to the craft main folder.

Comment: Wow haha, thanks dude, I was looking for something in the files of Craft! Cheers, sorry for dumb question :)

Comment: No worries, I'm glad to help! :)