# Hosting and permission problems

Tags: assets, url, config, projectconfig, configuration

It's my first time deploying CraftCMS and I ran into some issues which I don't seem to fix. I'm using Combell to host my website.

1. I can only access my site when I go to "sitename".be/web/ . The CSS is loading correctly but the images won't show up, I also would like to be "sitename".be/ to be the main path instead of the /web folder.
2. Suddenly the admin page it's css stopped working and I got around 50 cpresources 403 errors even though I did give the folder the right permissions.

Thank you in advance!

**fix Problem two:**
I managed to fix the second problem, when i set the file permissions it didn't apply to the subdirectories and their contents. So I had to change them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

About the 1st issue.
This is a server misconfiguration issue. You must configure your nginx/apache/another server to point the domain to the /web directory
Here is an base example for nginx

```
server {
    listen      8080 default_server;
    listen      [::]:8080 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root        /www/mysite.be/web;
....
}
```

[A similar question has already been asked](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/33612/how-do-i-change-the-web-directory) and  [another one](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/39623/website-transfer-places-web-in-all-urls-cs-and-js-not-loaded-when-moved-up-dir).

Comment: You need to point the hosting server to the public directory. On the settings page of the hoster, the domains root directory must be set to "sitename.be/web/" instead of "sitename".be".